# How can I modify values of matrix by using index values as vectors in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix as follows

```
 a =

     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
```

I need to modify values of following locations 
     (1,2),(1,5),(2,5),(5,3) as 5. I have row indices as 
    c =

```
     1
     1
     2
     5
```

and column indices as

```
d =

     2
     5
     5
     3
```

I tried to modify values using following command

```
A(c,d) = 5;
```

But it is not giving proper result it modifies indices of vector combination.
a =

```
 0     5     5     0     5
 0     5     5     0     5
 0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0
 0     5     5     0     5
```

but I need

```
a =

     5     0     0     0     5
     0     0     0     0     5
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     5     0     0
```

Can anyone help to get this result? Thanks in advance
Manu

Comment: [`sub2ind`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = zeros(5) ;
r = [  1
     1
     2
     5];

 c = [
     2
     5
     5
     3] ;

 idx = sub2ind(size(a),r,c) ;
 a(idx) = 5 ;
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in comments, one solution can be using `sub2ind`:

```
ind = sub2ind(size(a),c,d);
a(ind) = 5;
```